# Why do some Pokémon "glow"

Tags: pokemon-go

In the Overview of your caught Pokémon, some of them have a blue "glow" around them (see the two right-most Hornlius/Weedles and one of the Taubsis/Pidgeys in the following screenshot).

Does this indicate something special? Is this anything good/bad?

[image: Pokemon Overview]

Comment: @Wondercricket - yes, this is a duplicate. Must have missed that other question somehow.

Answer (score 7):

The blue glow indicates that the Pokemon was caught within the last 24 hours.